# How to debug non-working jQuery on mobile devices?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is my JavaScript code which is not executing properly. I think I am getting something wrong somewhere.

I want to add a search bar to make a search option in a responsive menu `navbar`. However, it is showing in desktop but not in mobile menus. That's why I am using jQuery to add this manually.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('ul').append("
            <li class='fusion-custom-menu-item fusion-main-menu-search fusion-last-menu-item'>
            <a class='fusion-main-menu-icon'></a>
            <div class='fusion-custom-menu-item-contents'>
                <form action='http://www.heilmancenter.com/' method='get' class='searchform' role='search'>
                    <div class='search-table'>
                        <div class='search-field'>
                            <input type='text' placeholder='Search ...' class='s' name='s' value=''>
                        </div>
                        <div class='search-button'>
                            <input type='submit' value='' class='searchsubmit'>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <input type='hidden' value='en' name='lang'>
                </form>
            </div>
        </li>
    ");
});
```

Comment: If that really is your code, then keep in mind: In javscript strings within `' '` or `"  "` MUST always be one line, so remove all linebreaks `\n`.

Comment: Are you getting errors in your javascript console?

Comment: hey @Leeish i just test my code on firebug on browser.

Comment: please help and tell me what can i do to add custom search option in the website menu in responsive view means mobile view.

Comment: What specific problem are you having on mobile devices? Which mobile devices? Have you looked at the browser/error console on devices that do not work?

Comment: hey @halfer i need to add this js under this media query to add the search bar option for mobile views,

`@media screen and (min-width: 240px) and (max-width: 767px){
 
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove new lines from the html: either concat all lines or put your html code in one line

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is that you mispelled the *function* keyword, the second one is that you are creating a mult-line string, but the engine doesn't know it and interprets the second line as a instruction. You need to [take a precaution](https://davidwalsh.name/multiline-javascript-strings), such as add a backslash at the end of any line.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   jQuery('ul').append("<li class='fusion-custom-menu-item fusion-  main-menu\
   -search fusion-last-menu-item'><a class='fusion-main-menu-icon'></a><div\
   class='fusion-custom-menu-item-contents'><form\
   action='http://www.heilmancenter.com/' method='get' class='searchform'\
   role='search'>\
 <div class='search-table'>\
  <div class='search-field'>\
   <input type='text' placeholder='Search ...' class='s' name='s'\
   value=''>\
  </div>\
  <div class='search-button'>\
   <input type='submit' value='' class='searchsubmit'>\
  </div>\
 </div>\
   <input type='hidden' value='en' name='lang'></form>\
   </div></li>");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: hello @criz your code is executed fine but it will add search bar option after every main menu. I need to add in the last of the menu. i.e. i need the <li> is for search option in the end not after every menu.